# Keep only lines that occur exactly once

Tags: python, duplicates

Say I have the text file test.txt which has

```
010101
001010
010101
000011
111111
010101
```

I want to write to a new file all lines that occur exactly once in the input file and delete all other lines:

```
001010
000011
111111
```

This code does not do what I want, because it only reduces duplicate lines to a single line, but does not remove them completely:

```
lines_seen = set()
with open("leadsNoDupes.txt", "w+") as output_file:
    for each_line in open("leads.txt", "r"):
        if each_line not in lines_seen:
            output_file.write(each_line)
            lines_seen.add(each_line)
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: show us what you tried ?
in general, after opening the file and reading it to a list, you can apply set(list()) to remove duplications..

Comment: @E.Gertz That won't produce the desired output. Note that the OP wants to get rid of **all** occurrences of any line that's duped.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes exactly this, so open a file, read each line, check for all occurrences of duplicate lines and remove them all. So its only completely unique lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to maintain a count:

```
from collections import Counter


with open("leadsNoDupes.txt", "w+") as output_file:
    lines = list(open("leads.txt", "r"))
    counts = Counter(lines)
    for line in lines:
        if counts[line] == 1:
            output_file.write(line)
```

This sort of over-collects information, as we don't really need to know if a line occcurs 2, 3, or 7 times, but it is linear nevertheless.